# Interesting sequence question (modified)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $N_0\in \mathbb{N}.$ If a sequence of complex numbers $\{F_N\}_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ has the following properties:
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |F_N|^{1/N}=0$$ and for all $N \geq N_0$,
$$|F_N|^2\leq \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} |F_k|,\quad \quad \quad  $$
then there exists $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_N=0$ for all $N \geq N_1.$

I would like to know if this is true or false. Could you provide me an example if it is false?.

Answer (score 1):

False. Take, say, $F_N=2^{-2^N}$.